# I have a mysql query where I am trying to add a count and a WHERE clause at the same time

Tags: mysql, count, where-clause

I have a query where I am trying to add a count and WHERE clause at the same time. I cannot figure it out at all. Any help on this would be greatly appreciated! My code(With the erroneous code commented out) is below:

```
SELECT 
                            RegDate,
                            DATE_FORMAT(RegDate,'%M') AS RegMonth, 
                            DATE_FORMAT(RegDate,'%Y-%m') AS RegMonthNum,
                            DATE_FORMAT(RegDate,'%M, %Y') AS RegMonthYear, 
                            DATE_FORMAT(RegDate,'%d') AS RegDay, 
                            YEAR(RegDate) AS RegYear,
                            #COUNT(SELECT * FROM Registration WHERE LMSCID = 14) AS Florida,
                            #COUNT(SELECT * FROM Registration WHERE LMSCID = 2) AS New England,
                            #COUNT(SELECT * FROM Registration WHERE LMSCID = 32) AS Colorado,
                            COUNT(SwimmerID) AS NumberOfSwimmers, 
                            CASE
                                WHEN LastYearRegistered = 2018 THEN 'Renewal'
                                WHEN LastYearRegistered IS NULL THEN 'New'
                                ELSE 'Return'
                            END AS MemberStatus
                        FROM 
                            (SELECT 
                                Reg_NewYear.SwimmerID, 
                                Reg_NewYear.RegDate,
                                MAX(Registration.Year) AS LastYearRegistered 
                            FROM 
                                (SELECT DISTINCT 
                                    SwimmerID,
                                    RegDate
                                FROM 
                                    Registration 
                                WHERE 
                                    Year = 2018
                                    AND TransferredOut = 0
                                     ) AS Reg_NewYear 
                        LEFT JOIN Registration 
                            ON Reg_NewYear.SwimmerID = Registration.SwimmerID 
                            AND Registration.Year < 2018 
                        GROUP BY 
                            Reg_NewYear.SwimmerID 
                        ORDER BY 
                            LastYearRegistered) AS SwimmersAndYears 
                        GROUP BY 
                            RegDate,
                            MemberStatus 
                        ORDER BY 
                            RegDate,
                            LastYearRegistered DESC
```

Comment: what do you mean  for "add a count and WHERE clause at the same time."  ,?  explain  you goal .  You mean that you want filter the result of the count values ?  show us a proper sample  ..

Comment: My goal is to take this line that works: COUNT(SwimmerID) AS NumberOfSwimmers, 

And have a similar line where it counts the SwimmerID but only where the LMSCID = 14. And then give a column alias of Florida in that situation

Comment: you have an error message  ?  .. show me?  . you have wrong result?  show your actual result ena the expected  result

Comment: Anyway  .. i have posted an asnwer as first suggestion

Answer (score 1):

Instead of this:

```
COUNT(SELECT * FROM Registration WHERE LMSCID = 14) AS Florida,
```

Use this:

```
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Registration WHERE LMSCID = 14) AS Florida,
```

Comment: I tried that but the number gives a total of all registrations with that LMSCID and not just for the day

Comment: This is more correct but it doesn't recognize the column name: 
 SUM(CASE WHEN Registration.LMSCID = 14 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Florida,